# My android app has an issue with fragment border

Tags: android, xml, fragment

Here is the screen shot from my app which has a border annoying me with not fitting on mobile screen:

[image]

Even if I try it with any layout (Relative linear or Frame).

This border pops up only when I use fragment in NAVIGATION DRAWER and this looks normally when viewed in Android studio design window but when you run on a mobile it adds the border to it has the attachment screenshot given above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#2579BF"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcircle"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/people"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcircle"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/email"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:hint="E-Mail"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="Contact Details"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/phone"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcircle"
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="322dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UPDATE NEW ACCOUNT"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrows"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcircle"
        android:backgroundTint="#b9b4b4"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="124dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/address"
        android:hint="Postal Address"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcircle"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Message Notification"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcircle"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/smsnotification"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Picture scan"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/sign"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="137dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcircle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/profilepicture"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></FrameLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E-mail Notification"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/emailnotification"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcircle"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: click the about link to see screenshot

Comment: can you post the xml of the activity that holds the fragment?

Comment: [Screen shot from the ANDROID STUDIO HELPING WINDOW](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m1d8qczxjoot8av/20160402043327.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: ...this is a screenshot of the fragment_adduser xml, i need to see the code of the activity that contains the fragment. Probably something like activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure op already solved this, but the solution is to remove all padding in content_main.xml. Just saying for other people who might run into the same issue.